# jqGrid: composite id syntax?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

```
$(function(){      
  $("#list").jqGrid({
    ....
    jsonReader : {
        id: "number" 
    },
    .....
```

Here I have a simple id which a column number.
Syntax-wise, How can I code composite id?

id= colunm a, column b, column c

Comment: Id s are unique , u can have multiple classes

Comment: ID can't have spaces so use `id= column_a`

Answer (score 0):

I understand, this is an old question, but this may still help others. Workaround here.
Basically you should supply the composite key in the json resultset in a single column.

In my case, I used Hibernate and `@EmbeddedId`, to encapsulate the composite key, this way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Sample")
public class Sample implements myEntityBase {
    @Formula("idPart1+'::'+idPart2")
    private String jqId;

    @EmbeddedId
    private MyCompositeId id;

    @Column(name = "setvalue", length=255, unique=true)
    private String value;
}
```

The MyCompositeId class is an `@Embeddable` id class, containing idPart1 and idPart2.

```
@Embeddable
public class MyCompositeId implements Serializable {
    private String idPart1;
    private String idPart2; 
}
```

In the jqGrid, you should reference the single, composed column as id:

```
$("#mygrid").jqGrid({
    ....
    jsonReader: {
        id: "jqId"
    },
    ....
```